# Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined. Node.js - bcrypjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, bcryptjs

No se cual es el error en mi codigo, se que es en la contraseña pero sigo sin saber que tengo que cambiar.
Este es mi codigo:

```
app.post('/auth', async(req, res)=>{
    const user = req.body.usuario;
    const pass = req.body.contrasena;

    let passwordHaash = await bcryptjs.hash(pass,8);

    if (user && pass) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario = ?', [user], async (err, results, fields)=> {
            if( results.length == 0 || (await bcryptjs.compare(pass, results[0].pass)) ){
                res.send('usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta');
            }else{
                res.send('login correcto');
            }
        });
    }
})
```

No sé que es lo que estaría haciendo mal o que tengo que corregir.

Este es el error:

```
\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:286
                nextTick(callback.bind(this, Error("Illegal arguments: "+(typeof s)+', '+(typeof hash))));
                                             ^

Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el error completo?

Comment: Tienes que depurar tu programa. Casi cualquier IDE actual tiene formas de depurar. En tu código no veo que valides si las variables recibidas en el `body` de la petición realmente existen o están indefinidas. Directamente pasas el valor de `pass` a la función de `bcrypt.hash()`. ¿Te has asegurado antes que `req.body.contrasena` es una cadena de texto?

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún `body parser` para analizar el cuerpo de la solicitud? Tu aplicación parece usar `express`. Si es así, esta librería tiene su propio analizador de cuerpo. Asegúrate de usarlo, para el caso de formularios: `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`, y para el caso de `json` agregas también: `app.use(express.json())`. Sin estos *middleware*, tu aplicación nunca podrá leer datos que vengan en el `body` de la petición.

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que hay dos errores en tu código:

1. La query que estás haciendo está retornando un valor de undefined en los resultados.

Primero revisa que efectivamente una query en SQL te retorna un valor dado. Mi intuición me dice que `.pass` no es el campo correcto que debes extraer de results, probablemente sea `.contrasena` o algo diferente. Revisa primero que estructura está devolviendo la base de datos.

2. No estás usando el `passwordHash` que acabas de calcular para pasárselo a `bcryptjs.compare`. Esa línea debería ser:

```js
            if( results.length == 0 || (await bcryptjs.compare(passwordHash, results[0].pass)) ){
```

---

Puede que lo mencionado no sea la solución final, pero estaré atento a iterar sobre el progreso que vayas haciendo.